# Sync MySQL schemas between different databases

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of databases that have the exact same structure than my "master" database, but after a couple of months, the developers did small changes (like, add another column, change a datatype to fix an error, etc) and they forgot to replicate it overall databases.

After some research, I found out that `mysqldiff` could generate the queries to update the databases left behind. But since I am using MySQL 8, it doesn't work (**ERROR: Query failed. 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist**), and the project (mysql-utilities) looks like got abandoned (the last commit is from 2016)...

Does anyone know a free alternative for mysqldiff? I just need to sync the databases, not the data. I am asking because most questions that I looked up where a little bit old.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench did the trick.
If anyone reading this wants to do the same thing, go to File, create a new model, then go to Database (the menu is different, lol), and then go to Synchronize with Any Source.
I just selected the source and since the databases were on the same server, I selected the overwrite option to change the destination database.